# Xml to SQL Server 2008

Tags: .net, xml, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0

Is it possible to create SQL tables every time I read XML files OR to implement this we must have a pre-designed table and just to add fields in the available tables.

If it is possible to create a new table every time then how it is possible? If not, then why?

Comment: Can you expand on what tools you're using to do this? Your question is a bit sparse on detail.

Comment: sql server 2008,.net 4.0,visual studio 2010

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What have you tried so far?

Comment: actually i want to import xml file in sql and doing some r & d on it.

Comment: Does it have to be via your application? Can you use SQL Management Studio?

Comment: yes i can use sql manant studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the tools you've identified there is no reason that you cannot create SQL tables on the fly from an XML file using a DataAdapter - as long as you've defined the Schema properly in the XML.  This link has a complete walkthrough.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/dataset.aspx

Halfway through the article search for the header titled "Updating the Database".  And note the following quote:  **"If your XML file contains any schema information then the DataSet will detect and create the corresponding tables and enable any constraints automatically."**

Comment: thank you very much lazyDBA this is exactly what i wanted to do